# Screenshot prior to Android 5 Lollipop?

Tags: android

The documentation on android's docs pages show how to take a screenshot on Android 5 (Lollipop) using the Media Projection API here: http://developer.android.com/samples/ScreenCapture/index.html

My goal was to take a screenshot and get the RGBA byte array of it.

Can you please point me in right direction to accomplish this on older androids? Ideally I was looking for a cross version solution, which Media Projection API is not :( its only 5.0

Gratitudes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take a screenshot from your own program you can get the main View and make it draw itself into a Bitmap and save it (this way the system bars will not be present on the image).

I dont know any API to do this.

Something like:

```
View root = findViewById(R.id.content_panel);//this need to be the root
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
root.onDraw(canvas);
//Compress the Bitmap bmp to a file here.
```

Comment: Conversely, if your objective was to take a screenshot of an arbitrary screen, that is not supported in Android prior to Android 5.0.

Comment: Thank you Marcos and @CommonsWare I will test out your method Marcos thanks a lot. And CommonsWare thanks for that tip on that difference/speciality of Android 5 feature, I didn't know it was special but it totally makes sense.

Comment: Hi I am working with yatg in training him on Firefox addons but I am very new to Android, I am using JNI from firefox addons: https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-for-android-addons/blob/355f9a01464a0794c1084e8fdbab92c58503f49a/snippets/jni.js can you please provide the java code necessary to do this, this will help me immensely create the JNI version and teach yatg and the other students.

Comment: Thank you @marcos! By `R.id.content_panel` did you mean `R.id.content`? Because I cant find `content_panel` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html

Comment: Also Marcos `findViewById` is a method, I need a place to start. What the goal is, is a person presses a button, it waits 5 seconds for user to change to desktop or whatever screen they want to capture. Then when they are there the capture executes, and pulls it up in a canvas which the user can then edit. `findViewById` is not a static method so no starting point (ie: I cant do `Activity.findViewById`) :( We were trying to obtain the view as the user is seeing with their eye on their device.

Comment: I said: "If you want to take a screenshot from your own program"

Comment: And the R.id. is the root view of your Views inflated in a Activity

Comment: Thanks @Marcos I got this done and shared with yatg but you are right it is of own program. Do you know any methods for with phone ui as if vol up + power button screenshot for <Android 5. In Android 5 im using the new media api.